# Magento showConfig module is not working

Tags: php, xml, magento

I start study magento from [Magento for Developers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config) guide. So I create module with their names. But it is showing following error when i trying http://works.dev/magento/?showConfig=true.

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://works.dev/magento/?showConfig=true
Line Number 1, Column 2: <?xml version="1.0"?>
-^
```

(works.dev is my localhost domain. magento path is working fine.)

This is my configuration files.

app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Configviewer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
                    </Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Configviewer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Configviewer/Model/Observer.php

```
 <?php
    class Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer {
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'showConfig';
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT = 'showConfigFormat';

        private $request;

        public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {
            $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
            if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'){
                $this->setHeader();
                $this->outputConfig(); 
            }
        }

        private function setHeader() {
            $format = isset($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT}) ?
            $this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT} : 'xml';

            switch($format){
                case 'text':
                    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
                    break;
                default:
                    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
            }
        }

        private function outputConfig() {
            die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());
        }
    }
```

I did clear cache and check logs. I cant find problem from those.

Comment: hi <?xml version="1.0"?> should be first line in  app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Configviewer/etc/config.xml 
no space should be their before xml tag

Comment: There must be some wrong char at line 1, column 1, since the error message states the `<?xml version` starts at column 2. My guess would be an encoding issue. Which character encoding was used when saving the file? Or maybe a BOM issue. If your editor automatically places a BOM at the beginning of the file, deactivate it, save the file and try again.

Comment: You may have a lot of white space before the declaration.

Comment: I search <?xml line with space in whole project. I cant find line with space. I use sublime. I was working good for other project.

Comment: Already tried to remove the space in front of your `<?php` tag of your observer file? This could also be a reason.

Comment: @JürgenThelen - Yes it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According @Jürgen Thelen it was space issue. It had worked after remove space before the

Answer (score 0):

Ausuraya,can you please change  config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <configviewer>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model</class>
        </configviewer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>configviewer/observer</class>
                        <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
                    </Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
```